# Positioning divs relative to other divs

Tags: css

I have a design question, I'm not sure how to handle.

I have 3 side by side divs, the center one will have 5 sub divs which are to be placed offset around the adjacent divs (div1 & div2), some on the sides, some below.

Initially I had the center div (blue dashed line) positioned relative, and its sub divs positioned absolutely and placed with top, right, left, bottom.

I'm not sure that's an ideal approach, especially if I want to be able enhance for mobile layouts.

I attempted manually positioning element as follows, but it seems very cumbersome:

```
<div class="col col-2">
    <div class="items">
        <div class="item item-1">1</div>
    </div>
</div>

.col { position:relative; }
.item { width:55px;height:55px; position:absolute; }
.item.item-1 { top:0; left:0; }
```

Full example here:

- https://jsfiddle.net/soch/fxgmq6om/1/

I'd love insight on approaching this,

Thanks,
S.

[image: Sample layout]

Comment: Show us what you have already.

Comment: Please post the html/css you have so far

Comment: The approach is not bad, or at least that's what i would try to do. It depends also and how you want/need to display stuff at certain viewport

Comment: It is not easy to layout elements like that without using absolute positioning. For mobile/small screen you can use media queries to make it work perfect, so need for a second approach.

Comment: There are many ways to handle this sort of layout, but [here's how I would approach it](https://jsfiddle.net/michaelwagner/024nw3da/) using floated containing elements and relative positioning.